# Why is agent returning nil and not waiting in clojure?

Tags: concurrency, clojure

```
(def file (agent nil))

(defn read-file []
    (if (= @file nil)
        (do
            (println "read-file")
            (send-off file #(slurp %2) (io/resource "file.txt")))
        nil)
    @file)
```

Here if I call `read-file` for the first time, it returns nil. For all subsequent calls it returns the file content. Why is that? It works correctly when I use `atom`. Also why is `#(slurp %2)` require the second argument? It is not working when I give just `%`? I am getting the following error:

```
clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (2) passed to: core/read-file/fn--3603
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deref on an agent provides a snapshot of the current state. The agent is initialized with `nil`, so dereferencing it in the initial state returns `nil`.

If you want to wait until the result has become available, you could use a [`future`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/future#example-542692c9c026201cdc326a74) or call [`await`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/await#example-542692cdc026201cdc326cdb) on the agent. A `future` would be my first choice, if only one action yields the result. In this particular example I would just write `(slurp (io/resource "file.txt"))` without any concurrency construct though.

Comment: Thanks, adding `await` before deref is working. Do you know why in `#(slurp %2)` `%2` is required instead of `%`? If I am to use `future` means the `send-off` should be wrapped in a future right?

Comment: I am not able to get it working with future. It gives the same behavior. Do you have any example?

Comment: Btw, this code does not make sense to me. Why is read-file not just `(slurp (io/resource "file.txt"))`? instead of using an `agent`?
You need `%2` because the first argument to the anonymous function is the state of the agent.

Comment: I want to cache the result. Using `future` does not work.

Comment: @kadaj Then I would use an atom.
`(def content (atom (slurp (io/resource "file.txt")))`

Comment: Ah! that is better. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An agent is the wrong concurrency primitive for this. It has all the characteristics you don't want, and none that you do want. Instead, since the thing you want to cache is a single expensive operation, use a delay:

```
(let [file (delay (slurp (io/resource "file.txt")))]
  (defn read-file []
    @file))
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what he wants. delay defers the computation to the future, until you realize it. For example, this takes 20 seconds: `(time (do (def d (delay (Thread/sleep 10000) 1)) (Thread/sleep 10000) @d))`. Also it isn't clear if what kadaj does it expensive. He probably just wants to read a text file and store the contents somewhere. At least, that is what I understood from the conversation below my answer.

Comment: @MichielBorkent, in that case he can use a `promise`.  At any rate, an agent is clearly the wrong abstraction.